# Outline text with Imagick and Debian 7

Tags: php, text, debian, imagick, outline

I'm trying to create outline text with differents fonts on imagick.
On debian 7 and on 3 differents servers it's always the same.
The beginning of text is perfect but the outline seems to lost drawing points at the middle of the image.

Can you help please ? I'm searching a solution for maybe 6 months.
Shadow works perflecty but outline no.
[image]

```
   $font='Lobster.ttf';
   $n0='data/toto.png';
   $text="blablablabla-is-atest";
   $stroke_w=2;
   $draw = new ImagickDraw();
   $draw->setGravity(Imagick::GRAVITY_NORTHWEST);
   $draw->setFont($font);
   $draw->setStrokeColor("#000000");  
   $draw->setStrokeWidth($stroke_w);
   $draw->setFillColor("#ff0000");
   $draw->setFontSize(40); 
   $image_size = new Imagick(); 
   $metrics = $image_size->queryFontMetrics($draw,$text); 
   $width = $metrics['textWidth']+($stroke_w*2);
   $height = $metrics['textHeight']+($stroke_w*2);
   $strokeImage = new Imagick();
   $strokeImage->newImage($width,$height,new 
   ImagickPixel('#00000000'));
   $strokeImage->annotateImage($draw, 0, 0, 0, $text);
   $strokeImage->writeImage($n0);
   $draw->clear();
   $draw->destroy();
   $strokeImage->clear();
   $strokeImage->destroy();

   $r=rand(0,4000);
   echo'Image text = '.$text.' image name = '.$n0.'<br /><br /><img style="border:1px solid #000;" src="'.$n0.'?v='.$r.'" />';
```

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That really looks like a bug in the version of ImageMagick that is being used by Imagick. I'm slightly surprised that your command line is ImageMagick 7, as that's a newer version than I would expect to see on that old a system. 
It's hard to know what to suggest, except maybe try it on a more modern system, find the earliest version that works, then figure out how to get that on your system.
Or upgrade to a supported Debian version.

Comment: Yes, it is.I will try to update debian version and start again.It's not so easy. Thanks for your message.